# Unusal loading error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am getting an unusual error which i dont know how to solve. Can any body please help.
My project takes a lot of time in loading.

```
Rendered /Users/Ahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@b_finder/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms[2012-10-29 22:29:43] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
/Users/Ahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
/Users/Ahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
/Users/Ahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


Started GET "/assets/home.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-29 22:29:43 +0530
Served asset /home.css - 304 Not Modified (3ms)


Started GET "/assets/list.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-29 22:29:43 +0530
Served asset /list.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/user.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-29 22:29:43 +0530
Served asset /user.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/js/less.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-29 22:29:43 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/less.js"):
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Ahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/Ahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/Ahmad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


Rendered /Users/Ahmad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@b_finder/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

I dont understand why it is giving such errors. One more thing ive noticed. 
I ve used twitter bootstrap `Tabbable nav` for that `js` is required. But if i m not connected to internet then that tab is not work. Although i ve manually pasted the js and all files of bootstrap in assets pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a loading error, in your case it can't find the less.js file.

Have you placed it in the correct position? 
app -> assets -> javascript

Comment: in the javascript folder the less.js file is in (another) js folder? (something like app -> assets -> javascript -> js -> less.js

Comment: yeah i ve pasted it in the javascript folder, the same path u mentioned. :(